# Google App Engine servlet only accessible on localhost

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404

**Java Code**

```
package com.practice;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

@Path("")
public class Hello{

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/keyboard")
    public String getkeyboard() {
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        json.addProperty("type", "text");
        return gson.toJson(json);
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.Practice</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I run the code on a local server (with Eclipse Jetty) and go to `localhost:8080/keyboard` it works fine and displays `{"type":"text"}`.

But when I deploy it to google app engine and go to `https://(app_url)/keyboard`, it gives me a 404 not found error. But then again, `https://(app_url)` gives me the welcome page just fine.

So I don't have the slightest idea why `https://(app_url)/keyboard` doesn't work.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is `http://(app_url)/keyboard` working?

Comment: @Bishan nope it didn't work, but i figured it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the capital 'P' in the package name 'com.Practice' in web.xml....i wonder how it worked locally though..i'll leave the question in case someone had same problem as i did

Comment: Please accept this answer, as the issue was solved. You need to wait 48 hours after posting to accept your own answers.

Answer (score 0):

According to out latest [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/quickstart), with `@WebServlet` annotation the `webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` is no longer required.

So in this case you could use something like this (adapting a bit the example code to your case):

```
    package com.example.appengine.java8;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

    @WebServlet(name = "HelloAppEngine", value = "/hello")
    public class HelloAppEngine extends HttpServlet {

      @Override
      public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
          throws IOException {

         Gson gson=new Gson();
         JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
         json.addProperty("type", "text");

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().println(gson.toJson(json));
      }

   }
```

Comment: i had to have web.xml since i was using jersey, thanks for the answer!